# read operation without fseek in a+ mode causes extra white spaces in the file

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

When I executed below code, m2.txt created correctly as expected with the specified data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char ch;
    fp1=fopen("m2.txt", "a+");
    fputs("Hello, data is appended\0", fp1);
    fseek(fp1,0,SEEK_SET);
    while((ch=getc(fp1))!=EOF)
    {
        putc(ch,stdout);
    }
     fclose(fp1);
     return 0;
}
```

Now I commented fseek and executed the below code. (I deleted this m2.txt file before executing)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char ch;
    fp1=fopen("m2.txt", "a+");
    fputs("Hello, data is appended\0", fp1);
    //fseek(fp1,0,SEEK_SET);
    while((ch=getc(fp1))!=EOF)
    {
        putc(ch,stdout);
    }
     fclose(fp1);
     return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, displayed data on the screen had just whitespaces. Even "Hello, data is appended"was missing. Also the m2.txt file had many white spaces.
Why this problem? If fseek is not done before read, it should affect only read operation I thought. Why extra spaces are getting written to the file?
In a+ mode, read pointer is pointing to the beginning if no write operation is done. But in case write operation is done, pointer will be at the end I suppose. In such case, read should not be displaying anything without fseek right? In anycase, issues could be there with read. But why write is having issues even though write is done before read.

I am using Codeblock 15.12 and default mingw came with codeblock.

Edited:
I further thought if it could be some compiler related issue. Grabbed old Visual Studio 6 and compiled. Several lines of unreadable characters are printed at the end. So it is not compiler issue. Somewhere some silly issue is there it looks.

Comment: if you don't use fseek, your cursor is at the EOF, because that is where you left it.

Comment: Aside: `char ch;` --> `int ch;` because that is the type returned by `getc`, see man page for why. `putc` also takes `int` data argument. And **always** check the return value from `fopen`.

Comment: I know if fseek is not used pointer is at the end. But my question is how it affect the write operation that is done before fseek?  Weather Vane: could you please elaborate your comment? I am not sure how getc is going to affect write operation? Also in my opinion, since the text I entered is char, there should not be any impact whether it is int or char.

Answer (score 0):

After some search, I found that fflush() or fclose() or fseek() is needed before reading the file. Otherwise the entire write buffer may be filled/affected. Tried with fflush() and write operation did not write any junk at the end even if fseek() is not called. Here is the code (Of course fseek() will be there inplace of fflush() in actual code. I just commented fseek and added fflush() for testing purpose).

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char ch;
    fp1=fopen("m2.txt", "a+");
    fputs("Hello, data is appended", fp1);
    fflush(fp1);
   // fseek(fp1,0,SEEK_SET);
    while((ch=getc(fp1))!=EOF)
    {
        putchar(ch);
    }
     fclose(fp1);
     return (0);
}
```